# how to update an empty dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, caching

if I initiate an empty dictionary {}, and I have two lists

```
var1 = ['trade1', 'trade2', 'trade3']

var2 = ['swap', 'bond', 'caplet']
```

how can I update the dictionary to make it as shown below:

```
{'trade1':swap, 'trade2':bond, 'trade3': caplet}
```

after that, I may get more combinations, such as:
`var 3 = ['trade4']`, and `var 4 = ['Irswap']`

how to keep updating the above dict with those new trades to become:

```
{'trade1':swap, 'trade2':bond, 'trade3': caplet, 'trade4':Irswap, 'trade5':..}
```

finally, how to cache the loaded trades in this dict, for instance, if I got a new combination: trade1:xyz, because trade1 is already in this dict, it will not update this dict. Thank you!

Comment: `dict(zip(var1, var2))` will create the dictionary.

Comment: `dictionary.update(dict(zip(var3, var4)))`

Comment: Please just ask one question at a time.

Comment: If you don't want to replace dictionary elements that already exist, do the update in the opposite order.